# JS /JQuery Form Submit Delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've implemented this 'locksubmit' plugin http://blog.leenix.co.uk/2009/09/jquery-plugin-locksubmit-stop-submit.html where it changes the display state of the button to disabled.
I then want the form to be delayed by a few seconds before posting to the form URL.

What would I have to add in or modify to delay the form "post" once the user has clicked the submit button?

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Cancel the default form submit behaviour, and start a timeout at the same time:

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    var form = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function () {
        form.submit();
    }, 1000); // in milliseconds
});
```

This should be compatible with the locksubmit plugin.

See a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/7GJX6/

Comment: And why does this not cause infinite recursion and no form submission?

Comment: It's not recursive because of `e.preventDefault()` and using `this.submit()` instead of `$('form').submit()`, which would cause an infinite loop.

Comment: What is the different between `this` and `$(this)` that prevents the recursion?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for - modify `lockSubmit()` as such:

```
jQuery(':submit').lockSubmit(function(){
  setTimeout(5e3); // fancy 5 seconds
});
```

And with options object:

```
 jQuery(':submit').lockSubmit({
   submitText: "Please wait",
   onAddCSS: "submitButtons",
   onClickCSS: "submitButtonsClicked"
},function(){
  setTimeout(5e3);
}));
```

Basically javascript has to wait for all arguments to be resolved before executing the body. By setting timeout during the argument we delay the return.