# JS / JQuery form submit delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, delay

I'm trying to delay the submission of a form but only when i trigger the submit after the delay it does not send the post values.

this is my html

```
<form id="form_anim" name="form" autocomplete="off" action="index.php" method="POST">
    <input name="username" id="username" type="text" placeholder="Nome utente" autofocus required>
    <input name="password" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    <a href="#">Hai dimenticato la password?</a>
    <input id="invio" name="invio" type="submit" value="Accedi">
</form>
```

and this is the script

```
   $('#form_anim').on('submit', function (event, force) {
    if (!force) {
        var $this = $(this);
        event.preventDefault();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $this.trigger('submit', true);
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

help me please.

Comment: why would you delay it may I ask?

Comment: Why Submitting form `twice`?

Comment: also, what is `force` ? you cannot possibly use it

Comment: It looks like you've already submitted the form...

Comment: You're using $this before you define it

Comment: possible duplicate of [JS /JQuery Form Submit Delay?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100726/js-jquery-form-submit-delay) Haha I love how the name of both these questions are IDENTICAL

Comment: i need to animate the form-box before the login,i removed that parta from the code because that's note the problem

Comment: @vsync `force` is an extra made-up parameter to the event. It'll usually be undefined, but when he calls `trigger` with the extra parameter, it should pass that in; at least, according to the JQuery docs.

Comment: @Katana314 -  but why..would you go **all** the way to trigger the event again when you are already inside the function and you could call the form submit directly using native DOM? doesn't make any sense

Comment: @vsync Don't ask me. I was just responding to your "you cannot possibly use `force`" comment.

Comment: @gabricom - well, are you satisfied with this discussion ?

Answer (score 2):

This will effectively submit your form with a delay.

```
$('#form_anim').on('submit', function (e) {
    var form = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        form.submit();
    }, 2000);
    return false;
});
```

*(btw, you don't need jQuery for this, unless you want to support IE8 and below)*

### [Demo page](http://jsbin.com/rukafiroke/1/edit?html,js,output)

Monitor your network (via browser inspector) to see it in action

Answer (score -1):

note sure if you meant to submit twice?

```
$('#form_anim').on('submit', function(event, force) {
    if (!force) {
        var $this = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            event.preventDefault();
            $this.trigger('submit', true);
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

Comment: First prevent default, than do fancy stuff. Also giving an answer without knowing what is that force argument...

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to use a button without `type="submit"`:

```
<button id="send">Send</button> 

$('#send').on('click', function(event) {                       
    setTimeout(function() {
       $('#form_anim').submit();
    }, 2000);        
});
```

Comment: yeah sorry i copied the wrong code; i wanted to copy the code  you just posted, but it's not working; he send the submit but no post values

Comment: The problem is that you are canceling the submit each time

Comment: no, i checked with php and the submission is triggered but no values in $_POST. If i trigger the submit just before the timeout it works but obviously with no delay.If you have a solution please tell me,i'm trying to fix this for about 2 hours.

Comment: just tried.Not working, but now i know the problem is not the delay itself but the .trigger("submit").

Comment: $('#form_anim').trigger('submit', true); don't post values,even if not delayed. if i submit the form in the normal way with the input type="submit"  post values are sent.

Comment: try using $('#form_anim').submit();

Comment: that's wrong. you shouldn't do that. the right way is to bind a submit even on the form itself. never the button, whom it's it's default behavior

Comment: @vsync this is not wrong, because it works, I like to use .submit()

Comment: "works" doesn't mean it's not "wrong". for example, to stop global warming, killing every human being on the planet would work. But of course, it's a very good idea, specifically for that problem. but in general, it's a bad idea. Also, voting my answer down, out of anger is childish

Comment: In can say the same to you, because you voted down my answer too.. and there is no difference between my answer and your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try following code
It works smoothly

```
<form onsubmit="return delay('1')" id="form_anim" name="form" autocomplete="off" action="#" method="get">
    <input name="username" id="username" type="text" placeholder="Nome utente" autofocus required>
    <input name="password" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    <a href="#">Hai dimenticato la password?</a>
    <input id="invio" name="invio" type="submit" value="Accedi"/>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    function delay(a){
        if(a == 1){
            setTimeout(delay(2),2000);
            return false;
        }
        else{
            $("#form_anim").submit();
        }
    }
</script>
```